# When does the SQLite engine actually release memory buffer returned by sqlite3_column_blob()?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am wondering what is the lifetime of the buffer returned by sqlite3_column_blob(). The SQLite document says: "The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically". When does it occur, what is the trigger? If I have only one row table - can I assume that the buffer returned will be alive till closing the DB, in the case I am not performing any other reading/writing to this table?

Comment: See the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html

Comment: @ChrisStathis The explanation in this document is not enough: "The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically.". When is it freed, exactly? What is the trigger?

Comment: It says so - 

The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called.